# READABLE_STRING_GENERAL vs STRING

Tags: string, eiffel

When to use which type of STRING in eiffel? I saw using `READABLE_STRING_GENERAL` and having to `l_readable_string.out' to convert it to` STRING`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`READABLE_STRING_GENERAL` is an ancestor of all variants of strings: mutable, immutable, 8-bit, 32-bit, so it can be used as a formal argument type when the feature can handle any string variant.

`READABLE_STRING_32` is a good choice when the code handles Unicode, and can work with either mutable or immutable versions.

`STRING_32` is a mutable Unicode variant. The code can change its value.

`STRING` is an alias for a string type that can either be `STRING_8` or `STRING_32`. At the time of writing only a few libraries are adapted to handle the mapping of `STRING` to `STRING_32`. However, this mapping could become the default in the future to facilitate working with Unicode.

Regardless of the future, I would recommend using `..._STRING_32` to process strings. This way the code directly supports Unicode. The libraries are also updated in this direction. For example, `io.put_string_32` can be used to print a Unicode string to the standard output (using the current locale).

Comment: Does that mean `STRING` does *not* support Unicode? Is it 8-bit-clean, then?

Comment: @U.Windl `STRING` does or does not support Unicode depending on the class mapping. When it is mapped to `STRING_8` (the default as of time of writing), it is 8-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a follow-up (I know I am years late in posting anything).

[image: FWIW—here are the descendants]